# How to make sense of the math behind differential opamp

Tags: amplifier, differential, gain, calculation

My first question here!

So, I'm designing a simple fully differential amplifier. The final target will be to implement a low pass filter (but I'm not there yet). Although all seems perfectly fine in my simulation, I have some troubles with the math issue as you'll see below!

[image: to]

So, this amp has a differential gain of 2.35 V/V, which is ~7dB. Each branch (positive and negative outputs) offers a gain of 1.175. So far so good.

Now, when I do AC analysis (as shown in the graph), I get a rather flat gain of ~1.32dB (on the zone of interest). So far so good, since 1.32dB = 1.175 V/V.

Now, **my math question comes in**: How do I derive the differential gain of 7dB from the individual gain on each + and - branch?

I'm not really interested in all the math behind it, but since I want to interpret the AC response of my filter, I'll find a way to make sense of the plots I'm getting.

EDIT:

I have added a voltmeter to my simulation to be able to plot the difference, and sure enough, the gain is ~7dB, so it's definitely just a math question. It may be obvious, but I'm not able to figure it out!

[image]

Comment: my opinion is try less chat style and more technical  to try to be more technically write!..  All you need to say is my Specs are as follows: Gain. Offset, -3dB BW, peaking. 0.1dB BW @ Vout max.  or whatever then ** where your problem isafter reading the datasheet linked in your question (hint)

Comment: . NG is given by 1 + Rf / (total
impedance from the inverting summing junction to ground).

Answer (score 0):

An op amp is a very high gain amplifier.  It amplifies the voltage difference between the + and - inputs.  Connecting the output to the - input creates a closed loop negative feedback system, and the net effect is that it will try to drive the voltage difference to zero.

With the voltage difference zero, effectively no current can enter the - terminal.  Any current presented at the - terminal, by e.g. a voltage applied to the input resistor, must flow "around" the op amp, through the feedback resistor.  Vin/Rin = Iin.  Iout x Rout = Vout, and Iout = -Iin, so Av (voltage gain) = -Rout/Rin.

In the circuit at hand, Av = 499/205 = 2.434.  Av in dB = 20 log (Vo/Vi) = 20 log 2.434 = 20 x 0.3863 = 7.723 dB.